# How to use Cronbach's Alpha?

Tags: categorical-data, reliability, agreement-statistics, psychometrics, cronbachs-alpha

Is it appropriate to use Cronbach's Alpha for nominal variables? I have 20 nominal variables (two dimensions with 10 questions each) that ask about the characteristics of work performance.

The dimension dimension 1 has questions like this:
Example: Do you use electronic equipment at work? Answers: a) yes, every day; b) yes, almost every day; c) yes, rarely; d) non-use; e) I prefer not to answer.

The dimension dimension 2 has questions like this: Would you say that at work you have: a) friends; b) only colleagues (work relationships); c) friends and colleagues (working relationships); d) work alone; e) I prefer not to answer.

With measurements in just one moment, is it possible to check the internal consistency (unidimensionality), both in general and specific by dimension (dimensions 1 and 2)?

Can Cronbach's Alpha be used in repeated measurements to verify test-retest reproducibility?

This study is an example:

"For the purpose of comparison to previous studies, test-retest reliability and criterion validity analyses were also determined using Pearson correlation and Cronbach’s Alpha." (LEATHERDALE, 2014, p.3)

Reference

Leatherdale ST, Laxer RE, Faulkner G. Reliability and validity of the physical activity and sedentary behaviour measures in the COMPASS study. COMPASS Technical Report Series. 2014;2(1). Waterloo, Ontario: University of Waterloo. Available at: www.compass.uwaterloo.ca

https://uwaterloo.ca/compass-system/publications/reliability-and-validity-physical-activity-and-sedentary

Comment: Cronbach's alpha assumes unidimensionality.  It is invalid when applied to multidimensional responses. For the most part, your example dim 1 item seems ordinal to me, not nominal; the example dim 2 item is a mix of ordinal & nominal.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply!
In example 1, to be in fact ordinal I would have to exclude everyone who marked the alternative "I prefer not to answer", but I would have a large sample loss (> 30%), because in each question I would add more losses in the verification of unidimensionality. Eg Question 1: 10 losses; Question 2: 7 losses .... Question 10: 2 losses. Thus, totaling the exclusion of 30 participants.
Is it okay to use Alfa with these response alternatives? Would using standardized Cronbach's Alpha be an option?